# BFD: Dwarf Error: while profiling openmp program with HPCToolKit using GNU 4.7.2

Tags: c++, c, profiling, openmp, gnu

I want to profile an openMP program using the HPCToolkit tool.

I have installed hpctoolkit-externals-5.3.2-r3950 & hpctoolkit-5.3.2-r3950 (latest tarball source from the website) using the GNU 4.7.2 compiler.

I have added the hpctoolkit installation directory to my path.

However I am now encountering issues while profiling the code
This is what I did:
I want profile an openmp program with tasks: task_ex.c

1) gcc -fopenmp task_ex.c -o task_ex -O3

2) hpcrun ./task_ex 1024 4

3) hpcstruct task_ex

4) hpcprof -S task_ex.hpcstruct -I /home/priyanka/examples hpctoolkit-task_ex-measurements

This is when I obtain the following error:

***msg: Line map : /home/priyanka/opt/hpctoolkit-install-5.3.2/lib/hpctoolkit/ext-libs/libmonitor.so.0.0.0
BFD: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '4', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
BFD: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '0', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
BFD: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '886', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
BFD: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '38401', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.***
.......

.......

Any idea as to what this error means and how one can resolve this? Is this related to binutils or am I not compiling or linking the program correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had a problem with Dwarf version once. Without understanding the real origin of the problem, updating binutils solved my issue. Maybe that's worth trying...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this thread is pretty old, but...
you can compile (gcc) with -gdwarf-2 (-gdwarf-3 works as well on latest hpctoolkit) 
then this message disappear.